overide plain styling on <v-card-actions>
I'm using Vuetify. This is the basic setup for a <v-card> component:
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>MyCard</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text></v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn>Revert</v-btn>
      <v-spacer/>
      <v-btn>Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn>Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
<template>

This is a very basic setup, however all the buttons in the  section end up styled as if they had the plain attribute passed:
<v-btn plain>Revert</v-btn>


How do I get a "regularly" styled button in my v-card-actions sections?
Example of Vuetify 'regular' styling:


Do you mean like this?
Since v-btn inside the v-card will be added as plain button, just update the variant to flat should be ok.
<v-btn color="primary" variant="flat">Cancel</v-btn>

playground

Side not on why I didn't find this.  The docs I linked to above are actually outdated.  Note the v2 subdomain.  This is actually depreciating, however it still comes up first in many google searches.  The correct docs should have no subdomain.  There are no depreciation warnings on the pages.  Please learn from me.

yes, v2 is out of date :)
